# Action not found when string contains /

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i have a string and i want to pass it to id in action

```
@Html.ActionLink("test","GetData","Home",new {id="abc/cdef"},new {@class="abnc"})
```

and my action is

```
       public ActionResult GetData(string id)
        {
            return view();
        }
```

but it does not goes to action and gives error

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found The resource you are looking for has been
>   removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

how do i resolve this issue thanks

Comment: The slash you are putting in the id must be escaped in order to get the URL you want

Comment: what if i have a string with contains / ? is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**
This happens when you have `/` in `string` and you are passing it to action because the route considers it as another parameter so in your `abc/cde` the default route thinks `abc` as `id` but after `/` it does not finds a match so it gives this error

**Solution**

so to solve this add `*` like

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{*id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

what `/{*id}` does is consider everything as a value of parameter `id` including `/`

Comment: Thanks You for explanation